# Write Text/Values On 360 degree Circle

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I am working on a wheel chart design, I need help in positioning the text on the 360 wheel.

The wheel have 12 sections, each one of 30 degree. The text's offset from the circle outer line should be equal (or similar at least). like in the image below I have mocked up what I need in final result.

[image]

So far, What I have tried is splitting each section into separate variable e.g.

```
$section1_startX = 50;
$section1_endX = 70;
$section1_startY = 310;
$section1_endY = 480;
```

and then to place text

```
imagettftext($im, 15, 0, $section1_startX, $section1_startY, $black, $font, "05");
```

but this is to find/calculate pixels of each line I need to place.

I am sure there is better, dynamic and smart way to put the text at x,y positions based on its values in 360 circle.

can you please help me regarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you want to find a Point on a given circle with a given degree. Here is a function for calculating point on a circle. I think you can convert this to any other language easily.

```
public static PointF PointOnCircle(float radius, float angleInDegrees, Point origin)
{
    //radius -> Radius of Circle & Origin -> Circle Centre.
    // Convert from degrees to radians via multiplication by PI/180        
    float x = (float)(radius * Math.Cos(angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180F)) + origin.X;
    float y = (float)(radius * Math.Sin(angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180F)) + origin.Y;

    return new PointF(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot, it's clock wise, how can I do it anti-clock wise, like I mentioned in my question, my first block is on the left and moving anti-clock wise?by the way, here is the PHP function I converted from your snippet `function PointOnCircle($radius, $angleInDegrees, $origin)
{     
    $x = ($radius * cos($angleInDegrees * M_PI / 180)) + $origin[0];
    $y = ($radius * sin($angleInDegrees * M_PI / 180)) + $origin[1];

    return array($x,$y);
}`

Comment: simply subtract the angle from 360. i.e Target= 360-Input Angle

Comment: 360-inputAngle did anti-clock wise, but I meant to flip horizontally, like the first block should be as marked 1 in my image. Thanks anyway to help so far.

Comment: okay, thanks, I have achieved it by subtracting input angle from 180 instead of 360, e.g. 180-inputAngle, Thank you so much for the help.